# PhoneGap Build errors

Tags: xcode

I am new to PhoneGap and got these errors when I compile the bundled PhoneGap.xcodeproject
I am using osx 10.6.2 and xcode 3.1.3

What have I missed?

Many thanks
Don

```
Building target “PhoneGap” of project “PhoneGap” with configuration “Debug” — (5 errors, 3 warnings)
gap-phonegap-80458a0/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/lydonchandra/Documents/phonegap-phonegap-80458a0/iphone/build/PhoneGap.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhoneGap.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/lydonchandra/Documents/phonegap-phonegap-80458a0/iphone/build/PhoneGap.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhoneGap.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/o+/o+iwoDblFHa23jj9u8xkm++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/PhoneGap_Prefix-hacookbrellaoddmixprvtxegbot/PhoneGap_Prefix.pch -c Location.m -o /Users/lydonchandra/Documents/phonegap-phonegap-80458a0/iphone/build/PhoneGap.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhoneGap.build/Objects-normal/i386/Location.o
Location.m: In function '-[Location hasHeadingSupport]':
Location.m:33: warning: 'CLLocationManager' may not respond to '-headingAvailable'
Location.m:33: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
Location.m:33: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
Location.m:33: warning: '...' as arguments.)
Location.m: In function '-[Location startHeading:withDict:]':
Location.m:123: warning: 'CLLocationManager' may not respond to '-startUpdatingHeading'
Location.m: In function '-[Location stopHeading:withDict:]':
Location.m:136: warning: 'CLLocationManager' may not respond to '-stopUpdatingHeading'
Location.m: In function '-[Location locationManager:didUpdateHeading:]':
Location.m:151: error: request for member 'timestamp' in something not a structure or union
Location.m:154: error: request for member 'magneticHeading' in something not a structure or union
Location.m:154: error: request for member 'trueHeading' in something not a structure or union
Location.m:154: error: request for member 'headingAccuracy' in something not a structure or union
Build failed (5 errors, 3 warnings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the latest iPhone development kit installed?  I don't believe you do if you are using Xcode 3.1; 3.2 and up are the current releases.

```
Location.m:33: warning: 'CLLocationManager' may not respond to '-headingAvailable'
```

Specifically, this indicates that the declaration of `CLLocationManager` does not have the `-headingAvailable` method.  That method was added in iPhone OS 3.0.  Thus, I'd bet you have the 2.x series of the dev kit installed?

Comment: Thanks, I have to uninstall my Developers tool, delete the directory, and the install the proper iphone sdk for snow leopard. I had the iphone sdk for Leopard before.